# Display my company linkedin page updates on my site?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, linkedin-api

Is there a way to display my Company page status updates from linkedin on my site?
I have checked the API but all I can see is information about company and no status updates.

Comment: Doesn't look like it and there's not a plug in for that either: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/{id}/updates?event-type=status-update, be sure you have accesstoken.